# Getting the Neuron Weights for a Neural Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have trained a Neural Network as shown below:
[image]

`net.b` returns two values:

```
<25x1 double>
0.124136217326482
```

`net.IW` returns two vaulues:

```
<25x16 double>
[]
```

`net.LW` returns the following:

```
[]  []
<1x25 double>   []
```

I am assuming that new.LW returns the weights of the 25 neurons in the single hidden layer.

I don't understand what net.IW returns and where they get the number 16.

Please help!

**EDIT:** Added Training Code

```
netJan = newff(trainX', trainY', networkConfigJan, {'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
netJan.trainParam.goal = 1e-9;
netJan.trainFcn = 'traingda';
netJan = train(netJan, trainX', trainY');
```

Dimensions

- trainX has 10 columns, 2153 rows
- trainY has 1 column, 2153 rows

After this code, I go on to perform predictions with only 10 input columns, so the other 6 are something completely internal.

What I am expecting:

25x1 array telling me the value of each neuron in the hidden layer.

10x25 array telling me the weight of each 'line' going from input layer to hidden layer.

25x1 array telling me the weight of each 'line' going from hidden layer to output layer.

EDIT 2:

```
net = feedforwardnet( [25] );
net = train( net, trainX', trainY' );
size( net.IW{1}' ) % 10 x 25 , Yay!
net = newff(trainX', trainY', [25]);
net = train(net, trainX', trainY');
size( net.IW{1}' ) % 16 x 25, How is this possible?
```

Comment: do you know how many layers there are in the hidden layer? and how many neurons does each of these layers have? btw, i am assuming "IW" means inputWeights, and "LW" means layerWeights, right?

Comment: @scmg Hidden layer has 25 neurons. input layer has 10 neurons and output layer has 1 neuron.

Thus, I need a 10x25 array for input weights, and 25x1 array telling me the weight of each 'line' going from hidden layer to output layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your Very Hidden Problem**

Your data simply has `NaN` values in col 1,2,3,8,9, and 10.

```
>> sum( isnan( trainX ) )
ans =
     3     3     3     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

I filtered the results and got these results which make sense.

```
>> goodX = trainX( sum( ~isnan( trainX ), 2 ), : );
>> goodY = trainY( sum( ~isnan( trainX ), 2 ), : );
>> netJan = newff(goodX', goodY', [25], {'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
>> size( netJan.IW{1}' )
ans =
    10    25
>> size( netJan.LW{2,1}' )
ans =
    25     1
```

**Solution to Viewers with Valid Data**

Suppose you setup a NN like this.

```
% Dummy NN
trainX = rand(2153,10);
trainY = rand(2153,1);
net = feedforwardnet( [25] );
net = train( net, trainX', trainY' );
```

You should use `feedforwardnet` instead of `newff`.

> Obsoleted in R2010b NNET 7.0.  Last used in R2010a NNET 6.0.4.
>
> The recommended function is feedforwardnet.

Note that my call generates a similar NN to the following call for NN initialization.

```
netJan = newff(trainX', trainY', [25], {'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
netJan.trainParam.goal = 1e-9;
netJan.trainFcn = 'traingda';
netJan = train(netJan, trainX', trainY');
```

> 25x1 array telling me the value of each neuron in the hidden layer.

You simply need to propagate the input/neuron values to get this

> 10x25 array telling me the weight of each 'line' going from input layer to hidden layer.

```
net.IW{1}
```

> 25x1 array telling me the weight of each 'line' going from hidden layer to output layer.

```
net.LW{2,1}'
```

To test the sizes:

```
>> size( trainX )
ans =
        2153          10
>> size( trainY )
ans =
        2153           1
>> size( net.IW{1}' )
ans =
    10    25
>> size( net.LW{2,1}' )
ans =
    25     1
```

Training window

[image: Training window]

Network view

[image: Network view]